# Single Sign Out with IdentityServer3 from ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver3

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that uses third party IdentityServer3 for authentication. I'm trying to perform a single sign out from IDSRV after logout from my application, but without success.

When user logs out from my app, I'm calling the endsession-endpoint of the IDSRV and I can see that the IDSRV redirects the call to the logout-endpoint which results a page that says I'm logged out. But if I do a new login, I'm automatically signed-in, in the IDSRV so obviously I'm not completely signed out.

Any advice how to achieve this?

Comment: Not enough info, as this should work correctly.

Comment: I made a completely separated sample project with my own idsrv instance and it works fine. I think I can get it working based on the sample. May have something to do with idsrv client configuration.